# How to credit open source package if I just borrow a function

Tags: derivative-works

I'm writing an open source Python module.

Within my code is a function which I have adapted from a function which I found in an other open source package.

If that other package was a direct dependency of my project, then great, I would just list it as a requirement.

However, I don't want to include that other project as a dependency, because:

1. it does some other things which aren't relevant to my project, and
2. even if I did include it as a dependency, only to use this one function, the function as it's written still wouldn't work as I need it to.

So, how should I give credit to this other package? Is it OK to just list it in an "acknowledgements" section in the README?

Comment: What license is the module you're copying the function from under?

Comment: I just checked and they don't even list a license in their repo

Comment: How big is the function?  Is it possible to reverse engineer the functionality, and write one that does what you need?  Otherwise, you should contact the author and have them provide you with an explicit license.

Comment: It's pretty small - I ended up implementing my own version. This has served as a reminder to always include a license in anything I publish :)

Comment: Any idea why this was downvoted?

Comment: @ignoring_gravity Probably because what you are describing is not open source, and it does not show a lot of research effort, and is a bit vague and probably not helpful to other people. For example, you said you found a package that you want to copy into your code, and no license was specified in the code. Not specifying the license is the same as "not open source". There are already other questions available which address the topic of what license applies if there is "no license mentioned", so that means this question, as it is currently written, is not very helpful to other people.

Comment: @Brandin - makes sense, thanks for explaning! I'll make sure to write better questions in the future

Answer (score 6):

From one of your comments:

> I just checked and they don't even list a license in their repo

In that case, you have no right to use the code from that module. Try and forget everything you've seen of their code and implement the function on your own.

Comment: Great, thanks. What if it was a project using, e.g., the MIT license?

Comment: If it is MIT licensed, you would have to follow the conditions in the MIT license. If it were SomeOtherLicense licensed, you would have to follow the conditions in SomeOtherLicense.